# Gravity as Vector Field and Potential

Tags: vector-analysis, coordinate-systems, vector-fields, spherical-coordinates

Given is a mass $M$ at the origin of the coordinate system, and another mass $m$ which is locate at $\vec{x}$

I have to show that the force acting on $m$ is a gradient field.

My approach:

I define the vector field as:

$$\vec{F}(\vec{x}) = \frac{mMG}{|x|^2} \cdot \frac{\vec{x}}{|x|}$$

does it help if I parametrize $\vec{x}$ though spherical coordinates? In that case, how would I compute the "backwards" (integration) step to find the potential, $\vec{F}(\vec{x}) = - \vec{\nabla}\phi$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\require{cancel}$
Yes, you can certainly parametrize the vector ${\bf x}$ in spherical coordinates, in which case

$$
{\bf F} = \color{red}{-} GMm \frac{\hat{\bf r}}{r^2} \tag{1}
$$

and the potential is

$$
\phi = -\frac{GMm}{r} \tag{2}
$$

which certainly [satisfies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates)

\begin{eqnarray}
-\nabla\phi &=& -\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r}\hat{\mathbf r}
- \frac{1}{r}\color{blue}{\cancelto{0}{\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \theta}}}\hat{\boldsymbol \theta}
- \frac{1}{r\sin\theta}\color{blue}{\cancelto{0}{\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \varphi}}}\hat{\boldsymbol \varphi} \\
&\stackrel{(2)}{=}& -\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(-\frac{GMm}{r}\right)\hat{\mathbf r} \\
&=& -\frac{GMm}{r^2} \hat{\mathbf r} \\
&\stackrel{(1)}{=}& {\bf F}
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: but is it necessary ? is it really that more complicated with normal cartesian coordinates?

Comment: @Leroy Spherical coordinates exploit the spherical symmetry of the problem, for example,  in spherical coordinates it is very obvious that the angular momentum is a conserved quantity and, therefore, the orbit of the mass $m$ restricts to a plane. You can certainly arrive to the same conclusion using rectangular coordinates, but it is not as easy

Comment: I understand, specifically integrating the components of the field on by one is particularly hideous, but could you show the steps you went though to find the potential ?

Comment: @Leroy Sure, just look at the expression -${\rm d \phi}/{\rm d} r = -GMm/r^2$, integrate once and you get $\phi(r) = -GMm/r$

Comment: And we shouldn't go though the other two integrals, with respect to $\varphi$ and with respect to $\theta$, because only $r$ affects the vector field, right?

Comment: @Leroy Correct!